# Why density matrices in QFT are calculated only by going to Euclidean metric?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, density-operator, wick-rotation, entanglement-entropy

I have been reading a few papers on entanglement entropy. I noticed that whenever people calculate either the density matrix or the reduced density matrix of a specific region, it is usually done by first going to euclidean metric and then proceeding from there. Is this done purely for calculational simplicity or is there a more deeper reason? I also tried searching for papers where the calculation is done directly in Lorentzian metric, but wasn't able to find any. I would really appreciate if someone could shed light on this.